# The expected size of Aut$(G)$ for an unlabelled graph $G$ on $n$ vertices

Tags: probability-theory, graph-theory, expected-value, automorphism-group

Please forgive the rather imprecise title, this was the best that I could come up with that could fit in a line.

Let $n$ be a [large] integer. Pick according to the uniform distribution a graph $G$ out of the set $\cal{G}_n$ of $2^{n \choose 2}$ graphs on $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. It is known that the expected size $A_1$ of Aut$(G)$ is close to $1$.

> **Main Question:** Suppose however, we were to collapse $\cal{G}_n$ as follows:
> $$[\cal{G}_n] \doteq \{\ [G]; \ G \in \cal{G}_n \}$$, where
> $[G]=[G']$; $G,G' \in \cal{G}_n$; iff  $G$ and $G'$ are isomorphic. Now, let us pick a $[G]$ from $[\cal{G}_n]$ according to the uniform distribution on $[\cal{G}_n]$. What is the expected size $A_2$ of Aut$(G)$, where $G$ is a graph in $\cal{G}_n$ in $[G]$. Is it still close to $1$?

Now, let $A_1$ be the expected size of Aut$(G)$, where $G$ is picked according to
the uniform distribution on $\cal{G}_n$, and let $A_2$ be the expected size of Aut$(G)$, where $[G]$ is picked according to
the uniform distribution on $[\cal{G}_n]$ [and of course, $G \in [G]$]. Then  $A_2$ is what the Main Question above is interested in. We now make an observation in the meanwhle however: The inequality $A_2 > A_1$ holds. Indeed, each $[G] \in [\cal{G}_n]$ is a set of $\frac{n!}{\text{Aut}(G)}$ graphs $G' \in \cal{G}_n$ that are isomorphic but distinct. So $A_2$ is the expected size of Aut$(G')$, where $G'$ is picked from $\cal{G}_n$ as follows:

1. Give each $G \in$ Aut$(G)$ a weighting $\omega(G) = \frac{{\text{Aut}}(G)}{n!}$.
2. Then, letting $\Omega \dot = \sum_{G \in \cal{G}_n} \omega(G)$, pick each $G' \in \cal{G}$ with probability $\frac{\omega(G')}{\Omega}$.
3. Then $A_2$ is the expected size of Aut$(G')$. Note that in this probability measure, graphs with larger automorphism groups are given larger relative weight, and graphs with small automorphism groups smaller relative weight, than they would be in the uniform distribution on $\cal{G}_n$.

**Given a graph $G$ on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, the *automorphism group* Aut$(G)$, which is a subset of the permutation group $S_n$ on $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, is defined as follows: a permutation $\pi \in S_n$ is in Aut$(G)$ iff $\pi(i)\pi(j)$ form an edge in $G$ for each edge $ij \in G$ [where $i,j \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$].

Comment: I don't understand... If the number of graphs with multiple automorphisms has a density of $0$, then after the collapse, this density is even lower ($A_2 \leq A_1$) as this only reduced the number of members with more than 1 automorphism, so this density is still $0$.
By definition, $[G]$ is of size $Aut(G)$, not $\frac{n!}{Aut(G)}$

Comment: @caduck its the other way around. The complete graph $K_n$ has as its automorphism group all of $S_n$, and the only graph in $[K_n]$ is $K_n$ itself. The graphs w only the trivial automorphism group do the most collapsing; if Aut$(G)$ has only one element then $n!$ graphs collapse into $[G]$.

Comment: @caduk it's the other way around. Let $G \in \cal{G}_n$. Then the number of graphs in $\cal{G}_n$ in $[G]$ is $\frac{n!}{\text{Aut}(G)}$. The complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices, on the one hand, has all $n!$ elements of $S_n$ as its automorphism group, and the only graph in $\cal{G}_n$ in $K_n$ is $K_n$ itself. The graphs w only the trivial automorphism group each do the most collapsing, if Aut$(G)$ has only 1 element then $n!$ graphs collapse into $G$.

Comment: You are right, I'm dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density tends to 1 also for unlabelled graphs, see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128233/how-dense-is-the-set-of-asymmetric-graphs)

A good reference is László Babai. 1996. [Automorphism groups, isomorphism, reconstruction](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Elaci/handbook/handbookchapter27.pdf). Handbook of combinatorics (vol. 2). MIT Press, Cambridge, MA, USA, 1447–1540.
(see 1.6. Asymmetry, rigidity. Almost all graphs. Unlabelled counting.)